# Listview with checkbox, imageview, textview and imageview filled with an arraylist

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I want to make a listview that takes the data from an arraylist. 
This is an example of the single row

[image]

The checkbox is disabled by default, it only gets activates in a longitemclicklistener(for multiple delete).

The last image is a menu button that opens a menu list for delete, share, etc.

I have an arraylist(myList) with 100 numbers(Strings), For each stored name, I want to show/hide the image according to certain condition

I have this row:

row.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" "
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:checked="false" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/im_buho"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="                  TEXTVIEW"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_weight="0.66" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the activity_main.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I do that?

I don´t know how make my customadapter. With a simplearrayadapter is easy but I can´t use a custom row. Any help?
Kisses, Tatyana. Sorry for my English ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample custom adapter implementation:

```
public class CustomUsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
    public CustomUsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> users) {
        super(context, 0, users);
     }

     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        User user = getItem(position);    
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
           convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_user, parent, false);
        }
        // Lookup view for data population
        TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        TextView tvHome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvHometown);
        // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
        tvName.setText(user.name);
        tvHome.setText(user.hometown);
        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/codepath/android-custom-array-adapter-demo)

*You can inflate your `row.xml` by replacing `R.layout.item_user` with  `R.layout.row` and replace the `User` class by your own pojo*

Comment: Thanks, Gorcyn. How can I have the MainActivity.java?
This is my arraylist

ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList .add("900120120"), etc until 100 phones.
myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

But i don´t know how follow...
Kisses ^^

Comment: You can check the Source link, it is a entire exemple

Comment: Sorry I don´t see it. i´ll check the link. Kisses ^^